# How to subset one R dataframe with the values of another R dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes in R:

```
Died.At <- c(22,40,72,41, ...)
Writer.At <- c(16, 18, 36, 36)
Name <- c("John Doe", "Edgar Poe", "Walt Whitman", "Jane Austen", ...)
Gender <- c("MALE", "MALE", "MALE", "FEMALE", ...)
Date.Of.Death <- c("2015-05-10", "1849-10-07", "1892-03-26","1817-07-18", ...)
Pet <- c("cat", "dog", "cat", "cat")
df1 = data.frame(Died.At, Writer.At, Name, Gender, Pet)
print(df1)
  Died.At Writer.At     Name          Gender    Pet
1      22        16     John Doe      MALE      cat
2      40        18     Edgar Poe     MALE      dog
3      72        36     Walt Whitman  MALE      cat
4      41        36     Jane Austen   FEMALE    cat
.....
```

In `df1` not each row for `Name` is unique (i.e. there are several rows with the same author.)

The second dataframe `df2`, there is also a column `Name` with both authors from `df1` (e.g. Jane Austen) and completely new authors. This dataframe is also far larger.

```
print(length(unique(df1$Name)))
## output 1168
print(length(unique(df2$Name)))
## output 5572
```

I would like to subset `df2` such that the only names are the names from `df1`.

My idea was to do this:

```
subset_df2 = df2[df2$Name == unique(df1$Name)]
```

However, I would expect there to be 1168 unique author names here:

```
print(length(unique(subset_df2$Name)))
## output 880
```

That's less than I was expecting. Where is my error?

Comment: There is inconsistency in this statement "Each value in the column Name is unique. However, in df1 not each row is unique (i.e. there are several rows with the same author.)."  If each row in df1 is not unique, and some rows have same author, how is Name unique when df1 is constructed from Name.  Also in your code you have First.Name and Second.Name but they do not appear in df1?

Comment: @R.S. I edited the above---thanks.

Comment: `subset_df2 <- subset(df2, Name %in% df1$Name)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `match(df2$Name, df1$Name)` or `df2$Name %in% df1$Name` which return a vector of logicals the length of df2$Name, and logical TRUE where df2$Name is in df1$Name. You can then use this to index df2.

```
subset_df2 <- df2[df2$Name %in% df1$Name, ]
```

See `?match`

As for why your code did not work, please see the output of this exercise:

```
a = LETTERS[sample(1:10, size=15, replace=T)]
b = c(unique(a), LETTERS[15:30])
# compare
b == unique(a) 
b[b == unique(a)]
# vs
b %in% a
b[b %in% a]
```

Note also `b %in% a` is not equivalent to `a %in% b` and therefore `b[a %in% b]` would yield an incorrect result.

Furthermore, when indexing a data frame you need to provide a row range and column range.

Comment: It appears there is no difference between `subset_df2 = df2[df2$Name %in% df1$Name]` and `subset_df2 = df2[df2$Name %in% df1$Name, ]`. Is this correct?

Comment: You typed the exact same thing in your comment, but if you mean `match` and `%in%`, yes they are the same, see the help file for `?match` and under details how `%in%` is defined as `"%in%" <- function(x, table) match(x, table, nomatch = 0) > 0`.  `LETTERS` or `letters` are built in constants in R, a vector of the alphabet, see `?letters`.